# Why does not $$ accept type char

Tags: c, yacc

I dont understand why this is not working. I tried usind int values with $$, and it worked perfectly, but unless there is another way i want it to be with chars.
This is my .l file:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
%%
DEFINE return DEFINETAG;
BEGIN return BEGINTAG;
END return ENDTAG;
[A-Z]+[0-9] {strcpy(yylval.buf,yytext); return AUT;}
[a-z_]+(0|[1-9][0-9]*)? {strcpy(yylval.buf, yytext); return EST;}
(\{[^}*]*\})* {strcpy(yylval.buf, yytext); return CODC;}
[->;] return yytext[0];
[ \t\n] ;
. yyerror("Caracter Inválido");
%%
```

And this is my .y file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
extern int yylineno;
int r; int c;
%}
%union {char buf[50]; int val;}
%start gda
%token<buf> BEGINTAG ENDTAG DEFINETAG AUT EST CODC
%type<buf> desta daute dest dtraa dautt dtra
%%
gda  : gda desta dtraa devea {char ma[r][c]; printf("%d, %d\n",r,c);}
     |
     ;
desta: DEFINETAG BEGINTAG daute ENDTAG {$$=$3;}
     ;
daute: daute AUT dest {$$=$3;}
     |
     ;
dest : dest EST {r=r+1;$$=$2;}
     | EST {r=r+1;$$=$1;}
     ;
dtraa: DEFINETAG BEGINTAG dautt ENDTAG 
     ;
dautt: dautt AUT dtra 
     |
     ;    
dtra : dtra EST '-''>' EST {c=c+1;}
     | EST '-''>' EST {c=c+1;}
     ;
devea: devea AUT {printf("void %s(){\n",$2);} BEGINTAG deve ENDTAG {printf("}\n");}
     | AUT {printf("void %s(){\n",$1);} BEGINTAG deve ENDTAG {printf("}\n");}
     ;
deve : deve est CODC
     | 
     ;
est  : EST '-''>' EST {printf("if(estado==%s)estado=%s;\n",$1,$4);}
     |
     ;
%%
int main(){
yyparse();
return 0;
}
int yyerror(char *s){fprintf(stderr, "ERRO(%d):%s\n", yylineno,s); return 0;}
```

This my my error list:

```
gda2.y: In function ‘yyparse’:
gda2.y:16:12: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[50]’ from type ‘char *’
gda2.y:18:12: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[50]’ from type ‘char *’
gda2.y:21:18: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[50]’ from type ‘char *’
gda2.y:22:18: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[50]’ from type ‘char *’
```

Comment: char[50] is not the same thing as char* is and C throws a fit if you try to assign a char* to a char[50].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, it's not legal to assign to an array. For example, you can't do this:

```
 char c[50];
 c = "abc";  /* ILLEGAL */
```

Putting the array in a `union` doesn't get around the problem:

```
 union {
   char c[50];
   int  i;
 } u;
 u.c = "abc";  /* ILLEGAL */
```

However, oddly, you can assign one struct to another even if they include arrays:

```
 struct FiftyChars {
   char c[50];
 };

 struct FiftyChars a,b;
 strncpy(a.c, "abc", 49);
 b = a;                /* ¡LEGAL! */
```

`bison` and `yacc` don't let you avoid the rules of C. Since `$$ = $2` is actually translated into something like:

```
yylval.buf = yystack[top - 2].buf;
```

whatever `buf` refers to needs to allow direct assignment. So it can't be an array. But it **can** be a `struct` whose only member is an array. Which means you could change your `%union` declaration to

```
%union {struct {char c[50];} buf; int val;}
```

and then make appropriate changes throughout your code (such as changing `buf` to `buf.c` in your `flex` input file, and `$n` to `$n.c` in your printf's).

Alternatively, you could avoid the issue by just copying the strings with `strncpy`, and writing

```
strncpy($$, $1, 49);
```

instead of

```
$$ = $1;
```

in your actions. That should work fine with bison, although I don't know whether every implementation of yacc will handle the default action (`$$ = $1`) as a union copy (which would be fine) or as a typed copy (which would throw an error).

On the other hand, you might at some point need to ask yourself where the size `50` comes from. Is it absolutely clear that it's big enough? Do you check to make sure that a token is never longer than 49 characters? Is it possible that your code is full of potential buffer overruns?

Once you start thinking this way, you will see that it is better to define your union with a pointer to a dynamically-allocated buffer:

```
%union {char* buf; int val;}
```

Now there is no problem with assigning `buf` in one semantic value's union to a `buf` in another semantic value, and you can just use `strdup` in your `flex` file to initialize the `buf` field. But you now have another problem, which is that you need to `free` all those dynamically-allocated names, or live with having a memory leak.

Living with the memory leak is possible, though ugly, if all you are doing is building a small one-pass compiler. After all, when the program terminates, all of its memory will be released without you needing to do anything. That was the traditional style, although I suspect that the vast majority of programmers reading this answer will be outraged by the suggestion.

Unfortunately, it's not so easy to fix. The semantic values are passed from one stack position to another, and there's no easy way to know how many pointers there are to a given string of characters, or when the string is no longer needed. If you were using C++ as a base language instead of C, you could use `std::string`, which will deal with all these issue as well as the allocation of appropriately large buffers, but at the cost of doing quite a bit of unnecessary string copying. Or you could use shared pointers to std::string's, which would do the reference counting for you, again at a certain run-time cost.

My solution, for some time, has been to maintain a dictionary of "interned" strings -- that is, unique strings, in the lexer, and have the lexer return a pointer to a (`const`) unique string. That has the cost of a hash-table lookup for every string token, but it effectively deals with the garbage collection problem. At the end of the parse, the lexer and its associated hashtable of unique strings can be simply deleted. (Of course, if a string needs to survive longer than the lexer, it needs to be copied. But in many cases, that's just not a problem.)

Comment: Or you can use `strcpy ()`, I think.

Comment: @rodrigo: Yes, definitely. Added a paragraph for that option.

Comment: Actually, the yacc/bison default action is actually a union copy and not a literal `$$ = $1;`, so it will work even for array types in the `%union`.  But everything else you say is correct.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I checked it with a couple of versions of bison but not with all the possible options; I've still got a niggling feeling that I've been bitten by the default action, but I can't remember the details. (I also seem to recall that there was some implementation which handled the default action by doing nothing, which would certainly compile :) ). So I left a bit of a warning, but noted that it's fine in bison. I probably should have mentioned the fact that the stack gets much bigger.

Comment: @rici: Where the default action bites you is when you want an implicit conversion (eg, int to double) which happens if you use an explicit `$$ = $1` action, but does not if you use the default action (which copies the union, so does a bitwise copy).  Depending on the implementaion, the default copy might actually be a noop, as the value of `$$` is being pushed on the parser stack replacing the value of `$1`, so if it just adjusts the sp, no actual copy is needed.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: bison (at least since 2003, when according to the changelog the error was changed to a warning) has complained about rules with default actions where $$ is typed and different from the type of $1. And I did mention the no-op implementation in my previous comment, although I can't remember which implementation did/does it.